# Properties are null when calling a command method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

When `RefreshServices()` is called, both `SelectedComputer`and `SelectedCustomer`are null, even though they are not when I actually select them.

Why?

/edit: Forgot to post the buttons' declarations in the XAML. It's updated now.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainViewModel _main = new MainViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _main;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Border Margin="10">
    <Grid>


        <!-- Comboboxes -->
        <GroupBox Header="Computer" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0 0 4 4">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComputerNames}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComputer}"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      SelectedIndex="0"/>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Header="Customer" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0 0 4 4" >
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerNames}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      SelectedIndex="0"/>
        </GroupBox>

        <!-- Main list -->
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Services, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*"  Binding="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Machine Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding MachineName}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <!-- Buttons-->
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 4 4 4" Content="Start"
                Command="{Binding Path=StartServiceCommand, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=dataGrid}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4 4 0 4" Content="Stop"
                Command="{Binding Path=StopServiceCommand, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=dataGrid}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Margin="4 4 0 4" Content="Refresh"
                Command="{Binding Path=RefreshServicesCommand, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" />


    </Grid>
</Border>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotify methods
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

```
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    #endregion

    /*---------------------------- C U S T O M E R S -----------------------------*/

    #region Customer Properties

    private string _selectedCustomer;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _customerNames;

    public string SelectedCustomer
    {
        get => _selectedCustomer;
        set
        {
            SetField(ref _selectedCustomer, value);
            Services = Utils.UpdatedServices(SelectedComputer, SelectedCustomer);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> CustomerNames
    {
        get => _customerNames;
        set
        {
            SetField(ref _customerNames, value);
            Services = Utils.UpdatedServices(SelectedComputer, SelectedCustomer);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    /*---------------------------- S E R V I C E S -----------------------------*/

    #region Services Properties
    private ObservableCollection<ServiceController> _services;
    private ObservableCollection<ServiceController> _selectedServices;

    public ObservableCollection<ServiceController> SelectedServices
    {
        get => _selectedServices;
        set => SetField(ref _selectedServices, value);
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceController> Services
    {
        get => _services;
        set => SetField(ref _services, value);
    }

    #endregion

    /*---------------------------- C O M P U T E R S -----------------------------*/

    #region Computer Properties

    private string _selectedComputer;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _computerNames;


    public string SelectedComputer
    {
        get => _selectedComputer;
        set
        {
            SetField(ref _selectedComputer, value);
            CustomerNames = Utils.UpdatedCustomerNames(SelectedComputer);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ComputerNames
    {
        get => _computerNames;
        set => SetField(ref _computerNames, value);
    }

    #endregion

/*---------------------------- C O M M A N D S -----------------------------*/

    #region Commands

    public StartServiceCommand StartServiceCommand { get; set; }
    public void StartService(ObservableCollection<ServiceController> serviceControllers)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach(var service in serviceControllers)
                if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                    service.Start();
            RefreshServices();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }

    public StopServiceCommand StopServiceCommand { get; set; }
    public void StopService(ObservableCollection<ServiceController> serviceControllers)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var service in serviceControllers)
                if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped &&
                    service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)
                    service.Stop();
            RefreshServices();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }

    public RefreshServicesCommand RefreshServicesCommand { get; set; }
    public void RefreshServices()
    {
        Services = Utils.UpdatedServices(SelectedComputer, SelectedCustomer);
    }

    #endregion

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        #region Initialize
        _services = new ObservableCollection<ServiceController>();
        _computerNames = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        _customerNames = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        _selectedComputer = _customerNames.FirstOrDefault();
        _selectedServices = new ObservableCollection<ServiceController>();
        ComputerNames = new ObservableCollection<string> { Environment.MachineName, Environment.MachineName };
        StartServiceCommand = new StartServiceCommand(this);
        StopServiceCommand = new StopServiceCommand(this);
        RefreshServicesCommand = new RefreshServicesCommand(this);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out the equality check and return from Setfield?

Comment: Values are still null.

Comment: What do you mean it's a debugging issue? Yes, I have, and it's binding and building everything perfectly fine. Once the app is running and I click Refresh (or call refresh after services are stopped or started), the two values I need are both null.

Comment: So I assume `public void RefreshServices()` this is ran, set a breakpoint inside, check the values first, then step, are the values changed? If so, `Utils.UpdatedServices` what is this doing?

Comment: No, they are null. I do know how debugging works, I don't think that's the problem.. like I said. Everything is built and bound just fine. I select a new computer and all properties and their privates are set (I stepped through my code too :)). Same thing for my computers. So now at this point the app is still. Everything is built up. Now I click a button, my command is triggered, but all the values the were just set & bound are now null.

Comment: `UpdatedServices()` is going to return an Obs.Col. of `ServiceController`. Also, this works fine. But when trying to set the Services in the `RefreshServices()` I'm not even going into `UpdateServices()` since both values needed are null.

Comment: You created two instances of MainViewModel. You're getting the Commands, inexplicably, from a throwaway copy that's used for nothing else. Don't do that. Just delete that `Source={StaticResource viewModel}` from those bindings.

Comment: @EdPlunkett good eye, didn't notice this until you mentioned it!

Comment: What exactly is refreshservicescommand?  At first glance i thought it was using refreshservices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created two instances of MainViewModel. Whenever you see "everything in my viewmodel is null even though, at the same time, it isn't" on Stack Overflow, look for duplicate viewmodel instantiations in the XAML and the constructor.

You're getting the Commands, inexplicably, from a throwaway copy in `Window.Resources` that's used for nothing else. Don't do that. Delete `Source={StaticResource viewModel}` from those bindings, and I think they should work as they are.

Grid is a direct child of the Window and doesn't have its own DataContext, so this should be fine. Let me know if not. We can make it work without too much trouble.

```
<Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 4 4 4" Content="Start"
        Command="{Binding StartServiceCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=dataGrid}"/>
<Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4 4 0 4" Content="Stop"
        Command="{Binding StopServiceCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=dataGrid}"/>
<Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Margin="4 4 0 4" Content="Refresh"
        Command="{Binding RefreshServicesCommand}" />
```